# Resources$NotFoundException after updating system apps

Tags: android

I have a system app that is embedded on some devices, when I try to update that app to a newer version I am getting Resources$NotFoundException exceptions, after I reboot the device everything works fine, any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: It seems to be using the wrong dex file (the older dex file)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, turns out it was because I added persistent="true" to my application declaration. which prevents the app from being closed and causes the update process to fail ( until reboot ).